# When printing chars to a file in my Java program, only first char shows up, and I get error

Tags: java

I am in the middle of making a Java program that ciphers a message typed by the user and returns it to them. It is supposed to read the text in the text area and output it to a file, which is then taken character by character and changed into a coded message, which is outputted onto another file and then scanned and displayed. Right now I am just trying to make it so that the text is entered, then outputted, then taken character by character and outputted to another file and read and displayed; basically everything but changing the characters. 
However, only the first character of the message or word is outputted to the second file and displayed, and I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException exception. Getting the text from the text area to the first file works fine though.
Here is the code; the problem is probably in createCipher() where I have it marked

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

public class CodeMaker {
public File Cipher;
public int l;
public File message;
public char cipherChar;
public String finalCipher;
public Scanner charScan;
public Scanner scan;
public String cipherWord;
public int z;
public int words;
public File cipherFile;
public int n;
public String cipher;
public JPanel panel;
public JButton saveButton;
public JTextArea textArea;
boolean create = true;
private JFrame frame; 
public static void main (String[] args) {
    CodeMaker gui = new CodeMaker();
    gui.start();
}

private void start() {
    frame = new JFrame("Project TrenchCoat: Cipher Creator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    makeMenus();
    makeContent();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

}

private void makeMenus() {
    JMenuBar menuBar;

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu menu;
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Cipher");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new NewListener());
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));

    menu.add(menuItem);

    JMenuItem menuitem = new JMenuItem("Read Cipher");
    menuitem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));

    menu.add(menuitem);
    menu.addSeparator();


    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
            Event.CTRL_MASK));
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

    JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem("Help");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));
    helpMenu.add(helpItem);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    JMenu aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");

    JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About");
    menuItem.setAccelerator(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,
                Event.CTRL_MASK));
    aboutMenu.add(aboutItem);
    menuBar.add(aboutMenu);

}

private void makeContent() {
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Click a button to use its function");
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    label.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JButton createButton = new JButton("Create Cipher");
    createButton.addActionListener(new NewListener());
    createButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    createButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    createButton.setForeground(Color.green);

    panel.add(createButton);
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read Cipher");
    readButton.addActionListener(new ReadListener());
    readButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    readButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    readButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(readButton);
    JButton aboutButton = new JButton("About Cipher Creator");
    aboutButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    aboutButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    aboutButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(aboutButton);
    JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");
    helpButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    helpButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    helpButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(helpButton); 
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save Cipher");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new SaveListener());
    saveButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    saveButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    saveButton.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(saveButton); 
    textArea = new JTextArea(10,25);   
    contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);







}



private class NewListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        textArea.append("Type your message to be ciphered below, then click 'Save Cipher'. Remember, everything in the text area will be in your message, so delete this line.\n");

        }
    }
private class SaveListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        createCipher();
    }
}

private class ReadListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {


            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
            cipherFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            if (cipherFile == null) {
                return;
        }

            readCipher();
        }
        }

    private void readCipher() {

        try
        {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(cipherFile);
            while (scan.hasNext())
            {

                String cipher = scan.next();
                textArea.append(cipher);
                textArea.append("\n");


            }

            scan.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                    "I/O error in file\n\n     " +
                            cipherFile.getName() +
                            "\n\nThis program will close", 
                    "I/O Error", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    private void createCipher() {

        try
        {
            cipher = textArea.getText();
            PrintStream oFile = new PrintStream("Message.txt");
            message = new File("Message.txt");
            oFile.print(cipher);
            oFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("\n*** I/O Error ***\n" + ioe);
        }

        //problem is probably just below here


            try {
                 PrintStream oFile = new PrintStream("Cipher.txt"); 
                 File Cipher = new File("Cipher.txt");
                scan = new Scanner(message);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {

                cipherWord = scan.next();
                l = cipherWord.length();
                charScan = new Scanner(cipherWord);
                while (n<l) {
                     cipherChar = charScan.next().charAt(n);
                    oFile.print(cipherChar);
                }


                }
            }
            catch(Exception ioe) {

                System.out.println("\n*** Print to Cipher.txt Error ***\n" + ioe);

            }





            viewCipher();
    }

private void viewCipher() {
    textArea.append("Below is the cipher you created.\n Now you can copy/paste in and email it to the desired recipient.");



    try
    {
        File Cipher = new File("Cipher.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Cipher);
        textArea.append("\n");

        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {

            String cipher = scan.nextLine();
            textArea.append(cipher);
            textArea.append("\n");


        }


    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                "I/O error in file\n\n     " +
                        cipherFile.getName() +
                        "\n\nThis program will close", 
                "I/O Error", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }







    }



private class ExitListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

If you run the program, what is supposed to happen is that when you type in the text area and click save cipher, the text you typed is outputted back to you.
Any help is really appreciated...
Thanks!

Comment: To help yourself in the future, use `ioe.printStackTrace();` when handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In createCipher, change-

```
while (n<l) {
    cipherChar = charScan.next().charAt(n);
    oFile.print(cipherChar);
}
```

To-

```
for(int i = 0; i < cipherWord.length(); i++){
    cipherChar = cipherWord.charAt(i);
    oFile.print(cipherChar);
}
```

Read first on Scanner and its methods and try to understand before using them. Close readers/writers in a *finally* block. If an exception/error occurs while opening or reading or writing to a file, you won't be closing them in your current program as *catch* will be executed and *close* call won't be.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) uses delimiters to retrieve text, and your code is balking when it can't find a complete token.